# Select top percent, in SQL Server, is off by 1?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to use select statement to get 10% from 3661 records table. But I get 367 records in return, but I want only 366 records; but when I put 50%, I want to get 1831 records, not 1830 records. here is the statement I use:

```
SELECT top 10 percent *
FROM table_a
```

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, that's just how the [`TOP x PERCENT` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) works (relevant part highlighted):

> PERCENT
>
> Indicates that the query returns only the first expression percent of rows from the result set. **Fractional values are rounded up to the next integer value.**

If you want a different rounding scheme, you will have to do the calculation yourself:

```
SELECT TOP (SELECT COUNT(*) / 10 FROM table_a) * FROM table_a
```

This would use an integer division, which [truncates the fractional part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175009.aspx), i.e., it rounds down.

Since you want 50% of 3661 to yield 1831, I guess you want "*round half up*", which you would get using the [`ROUND` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx):

```
SELECT TOP (SELECT CONVERT(int, ROUND(COUNT(*) / 10.0, 0)) FROM table_a) * FROM table_a
```

Note that `10.0` instead of `10` is required to force a floating-point division instead of an integer division.

Comment: `SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(10.0, 'BaseType'), SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(10.0, 'Precision'), SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(10.0, 'Scale')`

Comment: if I need to top 25%, how should I do?

Comment: @user1188125: Do some math. ;-) To get 25% of something, you can either (a) divide it by 4.0 or (b) multiply it with 0.25.

Comment: I used it with some sub queries and calculate efficient number from dividing 100 by percentage @efficient = 100 / percentage for example for 25% calculated result is 100 / 25 = 4 as you mentioned. but it's not correct for other values for exam 60,70, ...etc. It seems TOP PERCENT is working more accurate than this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the description of the PERCENT argument from MSDN Page for [TOP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) for SQL Server 2012:

> Indicates that the query returns only the first expression percent of
>   rows from the result set. Fractional values are rounded up to the next
>   integer value.

However the [SQL Server 2005 version of the TOP page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) doesn't include the second sentence about fractional values being rounded up. I would assume the behavior is the same (partly based on your anecdotal evidence), and MSDN added it because people asked/complained about the behavior.